# Error Custom Action in Uninstalling

Tags: installshield, uninstallation, custom-action

I have created a Custom Action named UninstallDokan,which Dokan is driver for my software.I encounter the errorwhen I uninstall my program:
Error 1721:
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action:UnistallDockan,location:,command:C:\program Files  <86>\DoTask\Driver\DokanUninstall.exe
The CA is configured as follows:

```
Created a CA based on "New EXE > Path referencing a directory".
Working Directory: <empty>
Filename & Command line: "[INSTALLDIR]\Driver\Uninstall.exe"
Return Processing: Synchronous (Check exit code)
In-Script Execution: Commit Execution in System Context
Install Exec Sequence: After RemoveFile
Install Exec Condition: Remove
everything else was left at the default
```

Do anyone have any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally,I can fix my problem.I created [CA Data](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/AccessingProps-DeferredCAs.htm).
The CA Data is configured as follows:
Install Exec Sequence: After UnpublishComponents
Install Exec Condition: Remove

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a race condition.  If you are scheduling in commit execution that means you are running after  RemoveFiles probably already removed the EXE.   Also remember that if rollback is disabled that commit custom actions won't execute anyways.

Comment: thanks.dont remove Driver folder when my software uninstalling.

Comment: I set 'Deferred Execution in System Context' for 'In-Script Execution' but no changes applied.

Comment: Try moving the action before RemoveFiles (keep it deferred).

Comment: Thanks for Replyed to my question.
I installed Dokan with CA Of Install with Product and Dokan Created the folder in folder of my product.I will unistall Dokan with Uninstall file that itself created and this need to Admin privilege.
I change config but not changed and my program folder didn't remove when my program uninstalled.
I added Dokan folder to Directory table that changed WorkWorking Directory to Dokan.

Comment: You really should be looking at Setup / Feature Prerequistes.  Calling an EXE and doing out of process install activities is not considered a best practice.